# My apex collection is not displaying on my screen

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, oracle-apex

I've created a collection in apex
Everything seems fine session wise : the collection exists in the session when i add a member but for some reason it's not displaying on my screen.(site)

I've created the collection in a process in the header :

```
   Begin
   If apex_collection.collection exists(p_collection_name 
=> :P30_COLLECTION) then
   Apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name 
=> :P30_COLLECTION);
  end if;

Apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name => :P30_COLLECTION);
```

SELECTION OF COLLECTION :

```
select c008 as soc from apex_collections where 
collection_name = :P30_COLLECTION;
```

ADDING A MEMBER :

```
Begin
Apex_collection.add_member(
        p_collection_name => :P30_COLLECTION, 
        c008 => :G_SOC
) ;
```

NB : I've set the items before header & refreshed region after adding a member

Comment: When do you set :P30_COLLECTION?  If you refresh the report dynamically you may need to include P30_COLLECTION in the "page items to submit" attribute of the report region.

Comment: It's included‍♀️

Comment: It's fixed nevermind

Answer (score 0):

You have to add_member first after select statement execute
ADDING A MEMBER :

```
Begin
Apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name => :P30_COLLECTION);
    Apex_collection.add_member(
            p_collection_name => :P30_COLLECTION, 
            c008 => :G_SOC
    ) ;
    
    select c008 as soc from apex_collections where 
    collection_name = :P30_COLLECTION;
    end;
```

then refresh region